# AngualrJS ElasticUI Slider filter

Tags: angularjs, elasticui

I'm using ElasticUI: https://github.com/YousefED/ElasticUI

```
<ul class="nav nav-list" eui-aggregation="ejs.DateHistogramAggregation('dates').field('date_taken').timeZone(2).interval('1y').minDocCount(2)" eui-filter-self="true"   >

<div eui-filter="ejs.RangeFilter('date_taken').gte(verticalSlider4.minValue)" ng-model="filter.enabled"  eui-enabled="verticalSlider4.minValue" ></div>

<div eui-filter="ejs.RangeFilter('date_taken').lte(verticalSlider4.maxValue)" ng-model="filter.enabled" eui-enabled="verticalSlider4.maxValue" ></div>

</ul>

<rzslider rz-slider-model="verticalSlider4.minValue" rz-slider-high="verticalSlider4.maxValue"
            rz-slider-options="verticalSlider4.options" ></rzslider>
```

In controller if i use this scope 1 it's working fine .

**1.**

```
 $scope.verticalSlider4 = {
          minValue: 1990,
         maxValue: 2016,
          options: {
            floor: 1990,
            ceil: 2016,
            vertical: true,
                 showTicksValues: true
                 }
       };
```

but for dynamic result if i use scope 2 it not working

**2.**

```
$scope.verticalSlider4 = {
          minValue: verticalSlider4.minValue
         maxValue: verticalSlider4.maxValue,
          options: {
            floor: verticalSlider4.minValue,
            ceil: verticalSlider4.maxValue,
            vertical: true,
                 showTicksValues: true
                 }
       };
```

Please give me a suggestion.

Comment: "Not working" is not a technical term. What isn't working? How is it not working?

Comment: not able to get the verticalSlider4.minValue data in controller so we not able to pass the values in scope

Comment: if i use watch.  i can get the ejs.DateHistogramAggregation('dates') result values  from indexVM . but if i change the range in slider , the slider going back to the old range . thats the problem @Rob

Comment: Or just give me or suggest me ideas to use slider filter in elasticui @Rob

Comment: nearly 5 days im trying to solve this problem pls give me some suggestions @Rob

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps

```
$scope.obj= {
          minValue: 1990,
          maxValue: 2016,
          options: {
            floor: 1990,
            ceil: 2016,
            vertical: true,
                 showTicksValues: true
                 }
       };

$scope.verticalSlider4 = {
          minValue: $scope.obj.minValue
          maxValue: $scope.obj.maxValue,
          options: {
            floor: $scope.obj.minValue,
            ceil: $scope.obj.maxValue,
            vertical: true,
                 showTicksValues: true
                 }
       };
```